# What is the number above towers?

Tags: paragon

When I'm near a tower, a short horizontal bar is shown along the top of the screen with a progress bar showing the remaining health of the tower. There is also a number that ranges from 0 to 7 (maybe more). What does that number indicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the number of enemy minions in range of the tower. 
It exists on both sides:

- On an enemy tower (or inhibitor or core) it displays the number of your minions in range, so the number of minions it attacks before attacking you.
- On a friendly tower (or inhibitor or core) it displays the number of enemy minions in range, so the number of minions it attacks before attacking enemy heroes.

> [...] Towers have a visible health bar as well as an indicator bar, showing how many enemy minions are currently in range of the tower. [...]

[Source](http://paragon.wikia.com/wiki/Tower)